# Can an emitter receive shadows from another emitter in Blender Render?

Tags: texturing

Scenario:
[image]

Can I get blue shadows on the red plane?
And red shadows on the blue plane?

But, without using any external lamps...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Go to *World > Indirect Lighting*, and check that.  Then go down a little to *Gather*, and click *Approximate*